# Android emulator-5554 offline

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm having a problem with emulator-5554, it keeps telling me it is offline.

When I do a `adb devices` from the command line it says

**`emulator-5554 offline`**

Even after a fresh restart, I try that command and it still says it is offline.

The problem is when I try to install .apk files to the emulator using `abd install <path>` from the command prompt, it tells me that it is offline, if I create another device and run that one, then try to install the .apk files, it says I have too many devices connected. So in other words, I can't install my .apk files.

How can I get rid of that emulator-5554? I heard that if you do a restart, it should clear all the devices, but that does not seem to be working. It is like it is getting initialized when my computer starts up. Has anyone run into this issue?

Thanks

Comment: In order to determine whether the problem is the emulator try this: 1. Open an emulator. 2. Open another emulator. 3. `adb devices` to get the emulators' names. 4. Try to install the APK by excecuting: `adb -s NAME_OF_DEVICE install file.apk` 5. Tell us what happens.

Comment: I will give that a try when I get home (at work right now), I didn't know you could specify the device you want to install on. That should be really helpful. I will update in a few hours. thanks for the reply!

Comment: Thanks again for the comment. I was able to install the apk on the emulator doing what you said. The disconnected one still remains on my devices list, but all I wanted to do was install that .apk. Thanks again, it worked!

Comment: I think this question is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013624/android-emulator-frequently-disconnected-offline/13815712#13815712 Try to have a look at this thread.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but might solve your problem - `adb -d` specified usb devices rather than emulators, `adb -e` emulators rather than usb devices, and `adb -s NAME` I think can be used to specify specifically which device you want, though I'm unclear on whether the last one always works the way you think.

Comment: Go into Android Device Manager and stop emulator and right click and click factory reset.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In such a case, you can do all of the following in order to be assured that your emulator starts working again :

1. Go to cmd and type `adb kill-server`
2. Go to task manager and find `adb` in processes. If you find one, right click on it and click on end process tree.
3. In eclipse, go to **Window>Android Virtual Device Manager**, click on the AVD you want to launch, click on start and uncheck "**Launch From Snapshot**" and then click on launch.

That's it! It will take a while and it should resolve your problem.

Comment: This also worked for me (killing ADB didn't solve my problem, in any situations).

Comment: as soon as i killed that process tree, the adb running devices list cleared :) it worked. <3 thanks

Comment: In Android Studio, to change the virtual device Boot Option from Quick Boot to Cold Boot works for me.

Comment: Where can I find the "Launch From Snapshot" setting in Android Device Manager when I execute it from Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Only full unistall of emulator and XAML worked in my case. Google becomes too lazy to check each build

Answer (score 181):

1 . Simply "Wipe data" to fix this issue.

[image]

2 . If it doesn't work, go to emulated device and enable developer options > enable usb debugging

Comment: Uninstalling the app from the emulator did the trick for me. But it is the same idea as wiping the data

Comment: This helped ind combination with 'Cold Boot now' just below 'Wipe Data'.

Comment: Just enabling usb debugging and a cold boot was enough.

Comment: This screen is from Tools - AVD Manager

Comment: cold boot + usb debug

Comment: It might be due to the fact that i've recently enabled and then disabled developer mode on this emulator device. If I disable debugging after that I cannot see logs

Comment: In my case I just deleted all emulators in android studio then restart the PC and it worked. I'm using a real device

Answer (score 47):

The way that Android detects emulators is by scanning ports starting at port 5555.

The number you see in the `adb devices` list (in your case 5554) will be one less than the port that adb is finding open.

You probably have a process running that is listening on port 5555. To get rid of the "offline" device, you will need to find that application and close it or reconfigure it to listen to a different port.

Comment: The question was about ADB. ADB port numbers start at 5555.

Comment: "You probably have a process running that is listening on port 5555". This really helped as we were running another server on that port and had totally forgotten about it!

Comment: It always started on 5554 - on all my PCs (home and work ones)... and it's always EVEN (5554, 5556, 5558, 5560, ...) while using multiple emulators.

Comment: Frank, why do you think they're all even? It's because Android also uses the odd numbered ports in between.

Comment: This helped me too!  I had a port open on 5555 which shows up as emulator 5554 (?).  Everyone who has already tried nonworking"reboot the server" style answers should go ahead and portscan their localhost.  I assumed ADB would be using USB devices more directly, not looking at my local ports and making assumptions about there being an emulator there without even doing a protocol check.

Comment: Many thanks,also fix my problem. I can not belevie there is a  qemu process occupy the port.

Comment: Thank you, `lsof -i tcp:5555` helped me to kill right process

Comment: For me Tabnine was running on 5555 changed the port now I have no problem thanks!

Answer (score 42):

### This solution is for Windows.

(See [@Chris Knight's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26423404/3063884) for **Mac/Linux**)

1. Start Windows Powershell:

   Start -> type 'powershell' -> Press ENTER
2. Run the following command: **adb devices**

---

```
PS C:\Users\CJBS>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5656   host
emulator-5652   host
12b80FF443      device
```

In this case, 12b80FF443 is my physical device, and the emulator-* entries are garbage.

3. Per [@Brigham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10356594/3063884), "The way that Android detects emulators is by
   scanning ports starting at port 5555.". The port number is indicated after the emulator name (in this case 5656 and 5652). The port number to check is the emulator port number plus 1. So in this case:-

   5656 + 1 = 5657

   5652 + 1 = 5653

   So let's see which program is using these ports. In this case, the ports to check both start with "565". So I'll search for ports in use starting with 565. Execute: **`netstat -a -n -o |  Select-String ":565"`**

---

```
PS C:\Users\CJBS> netstat -a -n -o |  Select-String ":565"

  TCP    127.0.0.1:5653         127.0.0.1:5653         ESTABLISHED     5944
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5657         127.0.0.1:5657         ESTABLISHED     5944
```

4. The final field in this output is the PID (Process ID) - in this case it's PID 5944 for both of these two ports. So let's see what this process ID is. Execute: **`tasklist /v | Select-String 5944`**. Replace 5944 with the output of the previous command:

---

```
PS C:\Users\CJBS> tasklist /v | Select-String 5944

adb.exe                       5944 Console                    1      6,800 K Running         MyPCName\CJBS          0:06:03 ADB Power Notification Window
```

What a surprise. It's ADB. As noted by other answers, it could be other programs, too.

5. Now, just kill this process ID. Execute **`kill 5944`**, replacing 5944 with the PID in the previous command.

---

```
PS C:\Users\CJBS> kill 5944
```

6. To confirm that the spurious emulator is gone, re-run the following command: **adb devices**

---

```
PS C:\Users\CJBS>adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
12b80FF443      device
```

ADB re-starts (as it was previously killed), and it detects no more fake emulators.

Comment: Thank you, in my case VSCode has opened a port 5555 and created a ghost 5554 emulator. Closed VSCode for the time of the operation.

Comment: Thanks so much, just what I needed! And I got a thorough lesson in PowerShell commands too.

Comment: This works great and was the only thing that worked for me after 2 hours of research!

For windows: Step 3, just run  netstat -a -n -o, copy the contents and paste it in notepad and search for that port your emulator port + 1. Then run "taskkill /PID #### /F" where #### is your port. Then restart ADB and you are good.

Answer (score 32):

From the AVD Manager try the "Cold Boot Now" option in the drop-down. It worked for me!

Comment: This is probably the first thing people should try before going in these over-complicated other solutions...

Comment: thanks! I was struggling for almost 2 hours.

Answer (score 24):

If you are on Linux or Mac, and assuming the offline device is 'emulator-5554', you can run the following:

```
netstat -tulpn|grep 5554
```

Which yields the following output:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5554          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4848/emulator64-x86
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5555          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4848/emulator64-x86
```

This tells me that the process id 4848 (yours will likely be different) is still listening on port 5554.  You can now kill that process with:

```
sudo kill -9 4848
```

and the ghost offline-device is no more!

On macOS Big Sur and later, use

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep 5554
```

to find out the process.

Answer (score 19):

I finally solved this problem,
I had to go to the **Developer options** from the **Settings** in the *Emulator*,
then scrolled down a little, turned on the USB debugging. Instantly my device was recognized online, and I no longer faced that issue. I tried *restarting android studio and emulator*, killing *adb* process, but those did not work.

Comment: you are a hero!

Comment: Hi @Shamsul can you please describe how to access the Developer Options from the Settings, in the Emulator? I presume you are referring to AVD Manager, in Android Studio. I have the same issue described in this thread and have tried all the things suggested except your suggestion. I do not see any Developer Options for the Emulator in the AVD Manager.

Comment: Hi Eddie, the usual procedure to turn on the developer option is the same for emulator and real devices. Find the build number in the software information, tap on it repeatedly, after maybe 7-10 taps, you will see that the developer option has been enabled.

Comment: I resolved the issue by toggling `USB debugging` in `Developer options`. I am not sure why this happened out of the blue, but this resolved the problem.

Comment: This is what finally worked. It's crazy we have to do this on an emulator.... which is meant to be used for debugging...

Comment: I'm working with emulator :(

Answer (score 15):

I also had the same issue. I've tried all solutions described here, but they didn't help me. Then I've removed all emulators in the *Android Virtual Device Manager* and created new ones. The problem was in the **CPU/ABI** system image configuration of the *Android Virtual Device Manager*. My Windows10 machine emulator with system image **`x86`** is always offline, where the emulator with system image **`x86_64`** is working fine as expected. Just be aware of this

Comment: on my case, x86 system images windows 10, I just need to delete all emulator then recreate them

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent so much time trying to get this to work and this was my problem

Comment: Same here, but on Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you man!! almost 2 days dealing with this. You are a hero

Comment: @RodrigoIbarra glad to help. I also struggled)

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by opening my commandprompt:

adb kill-server

adb devices

After starting up, ADB now detects the device/emulator.

Answer (score 10):

**Enable USB Debugging into your emulator**

1. Settings > About Phone > Build number > Tap it 7 times to become developer;
2. Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging.

That's it enjoy

Comment: Re-enabling USB debugging helped me (turning off and on)

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I found some process that makes adb not work well.
You can try to kill some strange process and run "adb devices" to test.

It worked for me:
kill the process name MONyog.exe

Answer (score 9):

Just write

```
adb -e reboot
```

and be happy with adb))

Comment: This tells ADB to reboot emulator. It cannot work if it's marked offline.

Comment: works if you previously execute `rm -Rf ~/.android` to clean offline devices. Best command and only one to solve my problem. No `kill-server` or `start-server` did the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `-e` flag, but this is clearly my favorite solution!

Answer (score 5):

The "wipe user data" option finally solved my problem. just wipe user data every time you start the emulator. This always works for me! 
I use windows 8 x64 , eclipse

Comment: tried all above but worked with clearing wipe user data alone.Thanks

Comment: @SaiRam, you didn't try all above, because this hint was repeated in several answers. Also `Cold Boot Now` helps.

Comment: @SaiRam, sorry. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

open your emulator,

setting --> about emulated device --> click Build number repeatedly-->open developer options --> open USB debuggin

Comment: The problem is the emulator is just having a black screen. You can only do this if you can access settings.

Answer (score 4):

From AVD manager list at the actions dropdown:
Cold Boot Now

restarts it without all pain above.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have bluestacks installed? If you do, the background processes that it runs creates the offline device "emulator-5554".

Go to the task manager and end all the processes with the description of "Bluestacks"

Answer (score 3):

Try this ...

1. Close emulator if it Running.
2. Start Emulator again and wait for its online.
3. enter Command in commandprompt and press ENTER key : adb tcpip 5555

(Make sure that only One emulator running at a time.)

1. adb -s emulator-5555 emu kill
2. Press Enter Key....
3. Done.
4. check devices by command "adb devices" in cmd.

Comment: the issue is that it does not turn to be online

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I started in 'Cold Boot Now' and clicked on Message to allow the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try deleting and recreating your AVD?
You can manually delete the AVD files by going to the directory they're stored in (in your user's /.android/avd subdirectory).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did try that actually. Still there. I'm tempted to just re-install everything.

Answer (score 2):

Go to windows task manager and end process "adb.exe". There might be more than 1 instances of the same process, make sure to end all of them.

Comment: How about "adb kill-server"?

Comment: How about mac ?

Answer (score 2):

on linux or mac the port thats blocked will emulator-id + 1 so 5555 so:

`sudo lsof -i :5555`

will show you the pid of process that are taking the port (should be the second column) so to kill it:

`sudo lsof -i :5555 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill`

then adb (fake) devices will no longer show on the list

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the emulator was working with Oreo and lower, but not with Pie, and everything I tried seemed to have no effect. What finally worked was updating the emulator to latest (version 28).

Comment: me too... pretty annoying

Answer (score 1):

I found that the emulation environment comes up as "offline" when the adb revision I am using was not recent.  I properly updated my paths (and deleted the old adb version) and upon "adb kill-server", "adb devices", the emulation environment no longer came up as "offline".

I was immediately able to use "adb shell" after that point.

Answer (score 1):

If the emulator is already open or executing it will tell you is offline. You can double check on the Command Line (Ubuntu) and execute:

```
 adb devices
```

You must see your emulator offline, you have to close the running instance of the emulator (since the port will show as busy) and after that you can run your application. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything but only this one works for my case:
Use SDK manager, and reinstall the system image.
Android Studio, click Configure, SDK Manager, Launch Standalone SDK Manager,
Check all "Google APIs Intel x86* System Image", "Intel x86 Atom*System Image" and install. Then re-start Android studio.

You might have to reconfigure and wipe the virtual device with AVD Manager, make sure you choose x86 version.

Comment: For me , it was the x86_64 version that is working, the others did not work

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your enable ADB integration is marked;
go to Tools>Android>Enable ADB integration .

if doesn't checked , check this option and close your virtual device and re-open it . this worked for me.. good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

In MAC, you can use Activity Monitor utility, since, unlike Linux, we cannot use *netstat -tulpn* command in MAC. Search for the running instance of the emulator, typically *qemu-system-i386*. Kill that instance and you will see none of the ghost emulator running.

Simplest way to grab Activity monitor utility is to use spotlight search. just hit cmd-space and type in *Activity Monitor*.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my virtual device. The problem is due to the Oreo image of the virtual devices that have the Play Store integrated. To solve this problem I installed a new device without the Play Store integrated and all it was fine.

Hope it helps, Bye

Comment: what a weird situation, but it fixed it for me too.

Answer (score 1):

See [emulator-5554 unauthorized for adb devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898322/emulator-5554-unauthorized-for-adb-devices). On API 29 emulator I run `adb devices` command and got `emulator-5554 unauthorized` message. Then I created a new `avd` device from `Google APIs` image (in my case Q, x86), not from `Google Play`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, it could be that you disabled the **developer options** from the emulator or the **debug mode**.

In those cases the terminal will print `adb: device offline` when trying to perform operations.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete and created gear avd again.It will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause was that I had resumed a VM with android-x86 inside. Rebooting the VM with Android-x86 and restarting the adb server fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the fact that you have another virtual device installed on your machine. It might be **Bluestacks** as I also faced a similar problem. I uninstalled Bluestacks and then checked
  `adb devices`
It was running fine then.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have unchecked "GPU Host" and its worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Wipe user data from AVD manager and then enter adb kill-server and adb devices.
Wiping data also saves lot of memory space in the System .

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another possible solution here, which is what worked in my case.

I found there was a process called SpiceWorksEventProcessor running, which was tying up port 5555, and apparently being read by adb as an emulator. Killing that process was what finally removed that stubborn emulator device for me.

I'm not sure what this thing is, but if you have it, it might be the cause of your offline emulator.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

All above answers didn't helped,and then I deleted and recreated emulator all worked fine

Answer (score 0):

**step 01:** Delete current emulator from AVD manager
**step 02:** Add new emulator. select device => select system image, in this step go to **x86 images tab** and select one which has the target with **google APIs**.
**step 03:** Finish all steps. Your're good to go ️

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was the port forwarding in the NAT connection settings of VMware.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wipe data, your emulator still cannot connect to the internet.
[image]

Please check your DNS network and add DNS 8.8.8.8
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using the command line to start the emulator, and there is an option there:

```
-delay-adb "delay adb communication till boot completes"
```

Unfortunately, it stayed offline even after boot completed. Removing the option solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For mac users

Go to terminal and type adb kill-server and then go to force quit the application and find any emulator is running and click on force quit.

Answer (score 0):

try using `default` or `google_apis` system image and not `google_apis_playstore`, as the playstore image requires authentication.

See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55196967/1050542

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the AVD and re-installing again was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is the jdk version causes the issue. It should be **openjdk-8-jdk** for A-Studio **Chipmunk** (2021.2.1) to use, not the **openjdk-11** comes with the system preinstalled. After running:

`apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk`

The problem is solved for Chipmunk!

I found this solution as a side effort to solve sdkmanager issue encountered. The link [Fix sdkmanager java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError batchfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55436585/fix-sdkmanager-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-batchfile) gives the optimal help.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the lock on the AVD device will help in running Wipe data, cold boot now, delete, etc actions will work, if they are not working before.

Run below to remove the lock. AVD name is the name you gave when creating it.

```
rm -vfr ~/.android/avd/[AVD name].avd/*.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me and kill the emulator running in the background -

```
adb emu kill
```

Answer (score -1):

I just cleared all the open tap of terminal and i restarted my system then it started working.
[image]