# Android emulator error "5554 offline" after restart

Tags: android

I'm already read lots of form but didn't solve my problem,whenever I'm using launch from snapshot it says "android emulator 5554 offline" I'm new to android my operating system is Ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator-5554 offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152681/android-emulator-5554-offline)

Comment: Whenever I'm create a new emulator it work but after restarting it says Android emulator-5554 offline

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, in my case the problem was the USB debugging in developer option was turned off for a reason. check if it is on and do not forget to turn developing mode on by clicking 7 times on build number.