# Android device monitor emulator 5554 - offline

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Good afternoon! Not so long ago I began to develop an application for android. The application creates a database and write data through want Android Device Monitor pull database and view, but when you start, emulator-5554 switches to offline mode. I tried to solve the problem using the adb kill-server and adb start-server, to no avail. Prompt how to solve the problem? Used to develop Android Studio 2.3.

Comment: Kill the emulator and reboot it.

Comment: I Tried. Still not working

Comment: This issue recently started for me as well.  About as soon as AS 2.3 came out of beta.  Usually a kill-server and start-server does the trick, but this is a new issue.  I never used to get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator-5554 offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152681/android-emulator-5554-offline)

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem with u, but I found it work when I open the Android device monitor first.
1.close your emulator and android device monitor.
2.open your android device monitor.
3.open your emulator.
Then it work.I don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, the easiest working way is
First, Open Android Studio
Go to Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager - Find the emulator which has problem -> Right click on it and click **COLD BOOT NOW** .

This will restart the android system, it's just like you hold the power button of your Smartphone and choose Restart.

Comment: I just did this and it helped me quite a bit after running around for a lil' while trying to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to:

1. in `build.gradle`  change dependency to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`
2. disconnect all connected devices
3. `adb kill-server`
4. `adb start-server`
5. then start Android Device Monitor
6. and at last launch emulator from Android Device Manager

Answer (score 1):

- Open Android SDK
- Select Tab SDK Tools
- Update Android Emulator and package related

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to this problem. It was just a small thing.

**You need to turn on your developer settings** 
Steps for this :

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to About Phone
3. Touch on build number for seven times(after this you become a developer).
4. Go back and go to developer options
5. Turn on the USB Debugging.

**That is it . Your emulator will be online.**

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

I am using emulator Nexus 5X got same issue. This emulator work perfectly before i rebooted my laptop. After my laptop rebooted this issue raise.

I solve this issue after enabling/activate Developer Options on the Emulator.

How to Activate Developer Options on Emulator

1. go to **Settings**
2. select **About Emulated Device**
3. Tap **Build Number** 7 times

Hope this could solve your problem or other readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
adb connect localhost:5555
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Android Device Manager (ADM) by the command line script.

1. Go to the Android SDK tools folder %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
2. Run monitor.bat

You can ignore its ddms error message when ADM starts. It does not affect to access the emulator.

I created a shortcut of monitor.bat on my Desktop. So I just double click the shortcut to start it when I need to run it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use `Charles Proxy` on their emulator, you need to `enable USB debugging` in Developer Options.

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we need to find out which process happened to occupy port 5554, so use below cmd and opt:

**netstat -tulpn | grep 5554**

in the resulst list find the PID in the last column, then

**kill -9 PID**

refer to explanation of **netstat: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35299848)

Answer (score -1):

There is a really simple solution to this problem:

run the command:

```
adb reconnect
```

this brings back the device online, you can check by running `adb devices`