# emulator5554 offline in android monitor device

Tags: android, device, offline, monitor

I am very new in android development. Recently I am learning the storage tech in android studio, when I start the monitor and write something into a "data" file, I open the Android monitor device to check the file, but I see:
emulator-5554 offline unknown, 
so I can't find the file I want, how to solve this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TgNU.png)

Comment: check here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152681/android-emulator-5554-offline

Answer (score 0):

Try restart with

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

Comment: But it could not work, it still displays emulator-5554 offline