# After android studio update api 24 emulator showing offline

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using a MACbook. For one specific emulator its always showing offline. The emulator has a nexus 5 skin and is a api 24 build.  When i try another emulator its fine and works. i tried re-creating the emulator. when i run adb devices it says the "unauthorized".

I tried the following: 
I went into the developer settings of the emulator and allowed usb debugging if to see if that would help but it did not.  this happened after i updated android studio to 2.3. i also tried to wipe user data from emulator. What is going on here ?

UPDATE: THIS IS OCCURRing for my other emualtors above api 22 also . i had to switch to genymotion for now which seems to work fine and shows as online. it has something to do with updating android studio. after i re-installed studio and did not take the 2.3 update, the problem was resolved.

Comment: what is host OS? also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized

Comment: its a macbook and its just api 24 giving the issue.the port 5554 is not being used, i restarted the pc even recreated the imagine. that thread you recommended seems to be referring to a physical device. i am having trouble with a emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know the exact issue but it appears there are some bugs/issues with the latest updates.

Personally I am seeing my tests fail when run by `./gradlew` commands, but not when run via Android Studio IDE.

I experienced your `offline` issue as well, I found I could at least rectify this by running:

- `adb kill-server`
- `adb devices`

More info on this in another post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21330228/5096103

-- UPDATE --

After investigating this one a little more, I found there to be compatibility issues between Qt version `5.7.0` which the new emulator uses, and Ubuntu `14.04` and it's version of Qt. Whatever system you will be using, you will have some version of Qt installed.

I'm guessing this may be the cause/related to the issues you are experiencing.

I was successfully able to fix my system by downgrading the SDK tools from version `25.3.1` to `25.2.3`. I don't get the speed improvements of the new emulator, but at least I can run my tests reliably.

Going to try resolve the issues between Qt versions, and will update this if I can get the new emulator to work correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by turning on USB debugging after unlocking developer options of the emulator by clicking 7x on the build number.