# react native android emulator issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, react-native

i have a android emulator running in my local machine with below options:

```
emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_22 -netdelay none -netspeed full
```

and i am trying to run the react native sample app on the simulator by below command

```
react-native run-android
```

it runs fine first time and my changes in the files area reflected in the app on emulator but after some time my changes are not reflected and getting error in the app

```
[![!\[enter image description here][1]][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6syRP.jpg

when launching the app again by calling

```
 react-native run-android
```

getting below error

```
> Exception in thread "Device List Monitor"
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.checkConnection(EmulatorConsole.java:317)
>         at com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.getConsole(EmulatorConsole.java:231)
>         at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.queryAvdName(DeviceMonitor.java:248)
>         at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.updateDevices(DeviceMonitor.java:220)
>         at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$400(DeviceMonitor.java:65)
>         at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListUpdateListener.deviceListUpdate(DeviceMonitor.
> java:662)
>         at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListMonitorTask.processIncomingDeviceData(DeviceMo
> nitor.java:847)
>         at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListMonitorTask.run(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> can someone help in identifying the problem of react native package
>   and android emulator connectivity issue(it disconnect after some time
>   and changes in the files are no longer can be viewed in the app on
>   emulator)

Comment: after you run the react-native run-android command. you must start you server with react-native start command in your project folder. then reload you app.

Comment: i did not use the "react-native start " command first time and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

if you had application on your emulator, you must use 
`react-native start` if you use native code or use `npm start` if you use Expo on you device. And run your app on your device and do reload, so your packge server can connect to your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Run "adb devices" in cmd.  If you see "emulator-5554   offline", just do as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21330228).