# emulator-5554 unauthorized for adb devices

Tags: react-native, adb

I'm trying to get my react-native project to run on an android emulator while on a Mac operating system.  It worked fine on my windows.

On my Mac, I go to terminal and type `react-native run-android` and I get the error message:

```
$ react-native run-android
Scanning 616 folders for symlinks in /Users/John/Documents/myreactnativeproject/node_modules (17ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I type `adb devices` and I see

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   unauthorized
```

I go into the settings of my android emulator, I go to Settings Build Number to tap it several times to enable Developer options.  In developer options, I enabled USB debugging, disabled Verify apps over USB, and left everything else as default.  I shut down my android studio and emulator, restarted it.  But still, the same issues mentioned above.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

I just connected my android phone to my Mac.   When I run `adb devices`, I see this result

```
List of devices attached
YLEDU16B18004313    device
```

But when I run `react-native run-android`, I get the same error as above.  So maybe there is something wrong with my react-native set up instead?

---

**EDIT 2**

I was able to deploy the app to my android phone by adding these extra steps

- `chmod 755 android/gradlew`
- For some reason, when I type `echo $ANDROID_HOME` into the terminal, I get the result `/Users/John/Library/Android/sdk`.  But if I add the `echo $ANDROID_HOME` line to my `android/gradlew` file, it echoes nothing.  And when I run the `react-native run-android` command, the compiler complains that ANDROID_HOME is not defined.  So I have to type `export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/John/Library/Android/sdk` again, then running the `react-native run-android` command works and deploys it to my phone.

However, my emulator still doesn't work. The new error message I get is that `Skipping device 'emulator-5554' (emulator-5554): Device is UNAUTHORIZED,`.

But at least I have a temporary solution, and to debug with my phone.

---

**EDIT 3**

I got rid of the `emulator 5554 unauthorized` error by going into my Android Virtual Devices and deleting the virtual device.  Then I re-installed it.  And now my adb devices shows `emulator 5554 device`.  And I am not able to deploy the app to my emulator.

Comment: Can you add the complete error message please? There might be another reason since it says _"read the error above for details"_

Comment: @bennygenel ok I've put in all the error messages that I received right after the `react-native run-android` command.  I don't think there's anything useful there

Comment: Does the react packager start before the error?

Comment: @bennygenel it says `React packager ready. Loading dependency graph, done.`

Comment: I just tried to be sure, I created a new project and run `react-native run-android` without starting any emulators. Command goes through all the building stages and then gives an error about the not connected emulator. If you moved your android files from windows there might be some conflict that cause the problem. Did you try running  `cd android && ./gradlew clean`?

Comment: @bennygenel I get permission denied when I ran the `./gradlew clean`.  So then I tried `sudo ./gradlew clean` and I get this error `./gradlew: command not found`

Comment: @bennygenel hold on, I just chmod 755 the gradlew, now it's doing something

Comment: Even thought if it solves the problem you shouldn't be needing to do this. There might be some problem with your initial installment but I'm not sure what is it.

Comment: When you run `react-native run-android` it tries to run `(cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)` and it might be also getting `permission denied` error and can't complete the command.

Comment: @bennygenel ok interesting.  Yes now I get a different issue saying ANDROID_HOME isn't defined.  But from my terminal if I type `echo $ANDROID_HOME` I see the value `/Users/John/Library/Android/sdk`. And I confirmed that this path actually exists.

Comment: I'm not that good with linux or mac but can it be another permission issue like can't even get the variables?

Comment: Can I suggest you to try something? Can you run the app from Android Studio and not from the terminal command? If running from Android Studio doesn't start the packager you can start it with `react-native start` and then run the app.

Comment: @bennygenel OK, I got things to deploy to my phone.  Emulator continues to be a problem.  I added an Edit 2 explaining how I got things to work.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a temp solution but I still think that something is wrong in your installation. Creating a new project with the same version of react-native that you are using and testing if its gonna start from the command right away without any change might help to see if the problem is with your project or your os or something else.

Comment: @bennygenel ok I got rid of the `emulator 5554 unauthorized` message and now it shows `emulator 5554 device`, and it can now accept the react-native build.  Everything works now!  I explain in EDIT 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my mac system to deploy a react-native build to my physical phone by following Edit 2 in the question.

I got my mac system to deploy a react-native build to my emulator by following Edit 3 in the question.

I think the issue was generally caused by moving my project from a Windows dev area to Mac dev area.  Then probably a combination of different issues happened that cause builds to fail for each situation.

Answer (score 68):

In my case, Create a Virtual Device with Google APIs Image, not Google Play Image worked for me.

The problem occurs the only emulator that runs on Android Pie others don't.

In Android Studio

1. Open an Android Virtual Device Manager.
2. Create a new Virtual Device.
3. Select any Hardware you want.
4. Select any System Image which the Target is "(Google APIs)" not "(Google Play)" (If you don't found. Try to look at "x86 Images" tab or "Other Images" tab)
5. Done!

Comment: Item number 4 solved my problem i was using Google Play as system image just changed it to Google APIs.

Comment: thank you, it worked with Google APIs as system image

Comment: In Android S Preview it is still the same (use Google API).

Comment: Not applicable if you want to try google play services !

Comment: Is there any alternative? I need an updated Chrome for my tests, and there's no easy way to update Chrome on Google APIs images.

Answer (score 49):

Android emulators have by default "Usb Debugging" in settings. You just need to wipe the data of the emulator. Do the following steps. It will work :---

1. Close the emulator and run the command **adb kill-server** in the command prompt. If **adb** is not set in you path then you might run this command from directory where adb is present.
2. Click on **Wipe Data** option from avd Actions menu.
   [image]
3. Now run the emulator. It should work.

Comment: my emulator has not enabled "Usb Debugging" by default. I am using not studio but Android SDK Manager and this step doesnt work in me.

Comment: This answer is best

Comment: Worked for me by following your steps.

Comment: I tried the adb command several places but it doesn't seem to be installed/found.  I'm using Android Studio 3.5.1

Comment: If you have android SDK installed then adb can be found in platform-tools folder inside sdk

Answer (score 25):

create new Virtual Device, and make sure you choose Google API's. 
[image]

run the new device!. this should work

[image]

Answer (score 13):

In my case, following steps worked

1. `Wipe data` from avd manager
2. `Cold boot now`

Answer (score 7):

I managed to authenticate the adb on a Pixel 2, Android 9.0 (Google Play), API 28, x86_64 virtual device (Intel HAXM). The problem should be related to the Extended Controls (the 3 dots bottom icon menu, when the virtual device is booted), the Google Play menu, that is checking the version of the Google Play services. When adb is not 'unauthorized', this page is displaying the correct version, and the Update button opens inside the phone the Play Store with the Play Services app, so you can update it.

The steps I took to be able to authenticate are:

1. Make sure the USB debugging is turned ON in Dev setting
2. Revoke the USB debugging authorizations
3. Make sure the Extended Controls >  Settings > Advanced > Open GL options are set to the: 'Desktop native OpenGL' and 'Renderer maximum (up to OpenGL ES 3.1)', so the emulator interface, animations, etc, are fast!
4. Power off the emulator
5. In 'Your Virtual Devices' in Android Studio, click the down arrow in Actions > Select 'Cold Boot Now'
6. When the device boot, you have to be fast, the dialog to remember and accept the USB connection will show and disappear for like less than 1 second (again I guess related to some automation scripts kicking, idn).

If you manage to click the 'remember' and 'ok' checkbox and button before the dialog disappears, you are done. Else you have to Power Off and Cold Boot again.

After that, don't wipe your emulator, else you'll have to do that insane race clicking again!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with the same system image... the "authorize" screen appears after the cold boot, but lasts less than a second and then disappears... will try to find a way to it to reappear. 
Thanks, by the way!

Answer (score 3):

Creating an emulator with graphics set to "Software - GLES 2.0" worked for me (Nexus 6 image).

I was initially using a Nexus 5X image which didn't allow me to select the graphics option.

**NOTE**: I went through the steps mentioned in EDIT 2 and EDIT 3 by the OP before doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I run `adb kill-server` and `adb devices`.
the device will back again.
for Emulator, the default settings is debug enabled

Answer (score 2):

**2022 answer**

What a shame of thread: so many "answers", comments and upvotes and none worked. Nobody simply mentioned that the "adb unauthorized" is caused by the adb keys stored in ~/.android/adbkey and ~/.android/adbkey.pub After deleting and recreating them, the problem was solved.

Credit: [Android Emulator Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208828/android-emulator-unauthorized)

Comment: Not always the case. I could not fix the problem with the old emulator from SDK 25 and Android 7.1.1, it worked fine with Android 7.0.

Comment: that's not really an answer either, why would this happen?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if USB debugging is not enabled on the emulator device.

Go to the emulated device, enable the Developer options and enable USB debugging.

[image: enable USB debugging]

Comment: It hasn't worked for me for years, but on API 29 emulator I created an `avd` from `Google APIs` image, like in answers above.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a new emulator with Google Api. Wiping data didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting emulator and creating it again helped me on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I solved Problem

```
add ANDROID_SDK_HOME to environment variable

ANDROID_SDK_HOME  = D:\sdk
```

and unplug device

and use new cmd