# Flutter SDK is not authorized by AVD

Tags: flutter, android-virtual-device

I'm running Android studio as an administrator in Windows 10. The AVD is a Nexus 5X API 28. I'm trying to run the flutter demo, but the device drop-box still shows "no devices", it only has the "Open Android Emulator" option, which I clicked to start the AVD:

[image]

The output of

> flutter doctor -v

is:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.407], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at C:\Users\User\flutter_windows_v1.0.0-stable\flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (10 days ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 31.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[!] Connected device
    • Device emulator-5554 is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Unlike in a real phone connected via USB, here there is no authorization dialog when I start the AVD. How can I authorize the phone?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48722416/10269042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48660184/4689849) worked: Wipe data and Cold Boot.

Didn't work:

Note that in the Terminal of the Android studio, `adb` is not recognized (following flutter installation instructions). You can add the android SDK location path to the PATH environmental variable just to be able to run `adb`, but this won't give you more information than `flutter doctor -v`. The android SDK path should be already in Tools|SDK Manager, which is in my case "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk", nothing to do with "android-sdk-windows". Killing and restarting `adb` didn't work.

Logcat shows the message "Please configure Android SDK" (click on "configure", opens "Project Structure" window). The paths to SDK and default JDK are valid. Installing NDK miscofigured something else, so I uninstalled it and left this path field empty. Under "Project", all Version and Repository fields are empty.

Answer (score -1):

You should add ANDROID_HOME variable to your class_path

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Taken from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180210044548/http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/)

After that call flutter doctor -v and flutter devices

Comment: This could be a fix for issues with the Android toolchain or Studio. Nothing to do with unauthorized devices