# How to accept debugging dialog for Android Emulator via command line

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I'm writing an automated emulator script that will create and launch an Android emulator so I can run my UI tests from any machine and guarantee that it'll run on a device.

My current script creates an `android-27;google_apis;x86` device which works fine, but lacks google services so the maps in my app do not show.

I tried creating an emulator using `google_apis_playstore`, but when the device boots, it prompts with an ADB debugging prompt. Normally tapping this would be fine, but Im expecting to be able to run this on a headless server and wont always be able to.

Is there anyway to create the emulator that will have google apis + maps *without* having to accept an ADB dialog?

Here's my current shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run this script in root project dir

# Kill existing emulator
$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb devices | grep emulator | cut -f1 | while read line; do $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb -s $line emu kill; done

# Install system image
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86"
yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

# Create emulator
echo "no" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -f \
    -n "tester" \
    -k 'system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86' \
    -b x86 \
    -d "Nexus 5X"

# Start emulator
$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd tester &

# Wait for emulator to start
$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb wait-for-device shell input keyevent 82
while [ "`$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r' `" != "1" ] ; do sleep 1; done
sleep 5;
```

I get an error when using `google_apis_playstore` because it can't adb in to check if the emulator has started because of the dialog.

```
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

Seems silly that you would need to accept debugging permissions for an emulator?

Edit: I have submitted this as a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128271326

Comment: This is likely just an operation order issue. Try to `adb shell input keyevent` *after* emulator booted. Similarly `sdkmanager --licenses` should be accepted *before* downloading.

Comment: @SergiiPechenizkyi the issue is I cant do any ADB operations because the authorisation hasnt been granted to allow me to, that's the crux of my issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike `default` or `google_apis`, `google_apis_playstore` is enforcing authentication. It means that both `adb server` on host and `adb daemon` at emulator should share same RSA `adbkey` for communication. Documentation is here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Typically it works automatically. `adb start-server` command will create `adbkey` files and then `emulator/emulator` will copy them into image filesystem. But since it doesn't work in your case you would have to carefully verify where things got misconfigured:

- Running `adb keygen adbkey` generates 2 files - `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub`
- These 2 files needs to be copied to `$HOME/.android` folder (alternatively `$ANDROID_VENDOR_KEYS`) for `adb` server on your HOST
- Same 2 files needs to be copied to `$HOME/.android` folder (alternatively `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android`) for `emulator/emulator` on your GUEST. Typically HOST==GUEST but if you are running `adb` on desktop and emulator inside docker container they are different.
- Filesystem for emulator is cached so remove any previously created images. They wouldn't have key copied over.
- Optionally, it is suggested here https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#notlisted to call `adb start-server` explicitly before issuing any `adb` commands

> ```
> $ adb kill-server
> $ emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_25 -port 5557
> $ adb start-server
> $ adb devices
>
> List of devices attached
> emulator-5557 device
> ```

Comment: I posted a bug report to google and they responded with a fix that works, and it looks like its basically what you've posted so i'll accept as the answer. Thanks for the help! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128271326