# Android Emulator Unauthorized

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I've got a Pixel 2 emulator running Android Q. Whenever I boot the device there's no RSA popup, and no notification that USB Debugging is enabled. Whenever I run `adb devices -l` I get the following output:

`List of devices attached
 emulator-5554          unauthorized transport_id:1`

I've tried wiping the emulator and cold booting it, restarting the adb-server and made sure USB Debug is turned on in the emulator itself.

I tried it on both my desktop running Kubuntu 18.10 & my XPS 15 running the same OS. Has anyone found a fix for this?

EDIT:

It worked when I selected a hardware profile without the play services. Problem solved!

Comment: I've also put my investigation of this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55196967/624706

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Seems there was an issue with adb tools.

Taken from Android Studio blog: 
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/03/emulator-28112-canary-28025-to-beta.html

ADB from platform-tools 28.0.2 can now be safely used with the emulator. If you are experiencing issues with "unauthorized" emulators:

1. Exit all emulators
2. Delete ~/.android/adbkey and ~/.android/adbkey.pub
3. adb kill-server
4. adb devices Wipe data of AVD
5. Relaunch emulator

Comment: Thank you, its worked for me as i'm just move the AVD directory.

Comment: Worked for me too. Perhaps after it works, it's best to enter Developer options and turn on the "Disable adb authorization timeout". Else the problem returns if that emulator is not used for 7 days.

Comment: All solution dodn't work until i tried this. Thanks!

Comment: worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me as well. It is very important to 'Wipe Data' with the command that is available for the emulator entry in the list of available emulators that is in the Android Studio. Just delete data from C:\Users\<user_name>\.android\avd/Pixel_3_API_30.avd data directories does not help. Thanks again!

Comment: Doesn't work...
`$ adb devices Wipe data of AVD` just gives
`adb: adb devices [-l]`

Answer (score 7):

I created a device without the play store services, which connected instantly!

Comment: This worked for me! Tried various different emulators with Play Store services and none of them worked. They would either get stuck on the Unauthorized state or OFFLINE state. Running them from terminal kept presenting the following message: "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU."

Comment: Year 2020. Found this solution and worked for the npx react-native run-android command. Tried thousands of alt. solutions, until I erased all emulators and created a new Nexus 6 API 29 with Android Q without Play Store, then enabled developer options, usb debugging, etc. and run command again successfuly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It works for me!

1. Exit emulator
2. Wipe data of AVD
3. Relaunch emulator