# How to enable USB debugging for headless emulator via ADB

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

I have some headless emulators running on a server which I connect to remotely via adb, but I see from adb devices that they are `unauthorized`

```
androidsim:5561 unauthorized
androidsim:5559 unauthorized
androidsim:5557 unauthorized
androidsim:5555 unauthorized
```

so I took screen shot of headless device, and saw USB debugging needed to be enabled, but how can I enabled USB debugging on headless avd?

[image]

Comment: you can't enable ADB via ADB obviously

Comment: Four years later, were you ever able to get this sorted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to accept debugging dialog for Android Emulator via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948726/how-to-accept-debugging-dialog-for-android-emulator-via-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

don't know how to disable, but was able to confirm dialog with

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell input tap 1081 1420
adb -s emulator-5556 shell input tap 1081 1420
adb -s emulator-5558 shell input tap 1081 1420
adb -s emulator-5560 shell input tap 1081 1420
```

Comment: he needs to use ADB for that, which he is trying to enable...