# error adding adb forward: reattach the device

Tags: adb

I use Linux ubuntu and droidcam I have this error when turn on droidcam and try connect via usb wi

"error adding adb forward: reattach the device"

I try turn on and turn of development tools in my phone but still not workinkg

Any ideas?

Thanks.

I tried reinstall and detach my device but not work.

Comment: After enabling Developer menu on Android you also have to enable "Android Debug Bridge". On Linux you may also have to configure that adb is allowed to connect to the USB device. What output do you get if you execute `adb devices` on Linux?

Comment: Hello
Thanks for your answer


List of devices attached
ZE2224C5ZP device
emulator-5554 offline

I installed android studio

Comment: Make sure you have only one adb version installed (some programs include their own usually older version which is bad). Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152681/android-emulator-5554-offline